# Issue with "index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]" with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I am building an app which basically keeps track of the weight. For a better visual approach, I attach a screenshot:

[image]

**Short explanation of screenshot**: I have declared an NSMutableArray which stores the weights in index 0,1,2,3 (as marked with black color). The "initial" bar has nothing to do with this MutableArray. Everytime a weight is added, it's stored in a NSUserDefaults for later use.

What want to achieve is : when all items in the MutableArray are filled, that is, all bars are shown, I want to add another weight in a way that index 0 is removed, index 1 and 2 are "placed/moved to the left" by 1 position, and then add the new weight at index 3.

My issue is: At the time of adding a new weight after all bars are filled, I get this error:

> [__NSArrayM objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]

I am aware that this error means that the array is empty, I just cant figure out why.

This is the code which initializes the NSMutablearray the chart is loaded:

```
if([weightUserDefaults objectForKey:@"weightMutableArray"] == nil){ // If no weight has ever been inserted then initialize array.

    // We initialize the array, otherwise it crashes. 
    [weightMutableArray addObject:@"0"];
    [weightMutableArray addObject:@"0"];
    [weightMutableArray addObject:@"0"];
    [weightMutableArray addObject:@"0"];

    // We store this 1st time array initialization in the UserDefaults
    [weightUserDefaults setValue:weightMutableArray forKey:@"weightMutableArray"];

    }else{ // If we have a weight from the Inaction, then show it in the graph

    weightMutableArray = [[weightUserDefaults objectForKey:@"weightMutableArray"] mutableCopy];;

    NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    PNBarChart * barChart = [[PNBarChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, optionsUIView.bounds.size.width, optionsUIView.bounds.size.height)];

      [barChart setYValues:@[
      [f numberFromString:[weightUserDefaults objectForKey:@"InitialWeight"]],
      [f numberFromString:[weightMutableArray objectAtIndex:0]],
      [f numberFromString:[weightMutableArray objectAtIndex:1]],
      [f numberFromString:[weightMutableArray objectAtIndex:2]],
      [f numberFromString:[weightMutableArray objectAtIndex:3]]]];

      [barChart strokeChart];
      [optionsUIView addSubview:barChart];
      [optionsUIView addSubview:addweightButton];
```

And this is the IBAction to add a new weight. I am pretty sure the issue is in here as far as I've investigated.

```
for (int i=0;i < [weightMutableArray count]; i++){ // We start iterating in the array
  if(![weightMutableArray[3] isEqualToString:@"0"]){ // If index 3 is not 0, means its been filled
    [weightMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:0]; // Then we remove the index 0

   for (int j = 1;j<=3;j++ )[weightMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:j-1 withObject:weightMutableArray[j]];
    [weightMutableArray insertObject:[[alertController textFields][0] text] atIndex:3]; // whatever its in index 1, put it in index 0. Then whatever its in index 2, put it in index 1, etc etc.

            break;
   }else if([weightMutableArray[i] isEqualToString:@"0"]){ //if any index is 0.

    [weightMutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[[alertController textFields][0] text]]; // then fill data from the UITextfield.

            break;
        }
    }

    // After everything is done, just store it back in the UserDefaults.
    [weightUserDefaults setValue:weightMutableArray forKey:@"weightMutableArray"];
```

Comment: I don't know why you put `3` in the loop. Did you mean `i`?

Comment: You mean in the `j` for? I am thinking that I wanted to iterare in the indexes 1, 2, and 3 in the weightMutableArray. The idea is : weightMutableArray[j-1] = weightMutableArray[j] for index 1,2, and 3.

Comment: No i mean `if(![weightMutableArray[3] isEqualToString:@"0"])`. `3` means `i`. Right?

Comment: Ah ! now I understand. No because I want to remove the index 0 `whenweightMutableArray[3]` is not 0 (which means its filled), and that happens when `i` is 3

When `weightMutableArray` is empty, the `i` "enters in the "else if". But when `weightMutableArray` is filled, then `i` "enters" in the `isEqualToString`. At least thats what should do :) . What I can do is to recode what I want to do because maybe in this way now seems complex

Comment: You should take a look at Amin answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the first item first:

```
[weightMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:0]; // Then we remove the index 0
```

the array remains with values 3 in indexes 0-2.

Before the removal the array looks like this:

```
0: value1
1: value2
2: value3
3: value4
```

Since (Cocoa) arrays are always closed (compact), removing the first item pulls up the following elements. Now the array looks like this:

```
0: value2
1: value3
2: value4
```

Therefore there is no item with an index 3:

```
for (int j = 1;j<=3;j++ )
```

You simply do not have to move the remaining items up. It is already done.

But, let me say this with all respect, you misunderstood the whole concept of mutable collections and zeroing. It is a special version of the zero is null antipattern.

Comment: Did it. This is, what I meant with "misunderstood the concept."

Comment: Yes, I know I misunderstood the concept. I just didn't know or take into account that the `for j` that I coded, cocoa does it for me, so I was doing twice the same thing. Thank you :)

Comment: The problem with your code is from the very beginning (at array creation), that you use zero to represent an "empty", non-existing element.